# wkhtmltopdf & debian - install

Tags: debian, apt, qt, xvfb

I have a question about the installation of `wkhtmltopdf` on Debian machines via the `apt-get` command.
So far, I've tested three environments, with different results, and I'd like to better understand the reasons why the outcome is never as expected.

1. **Laptop** with Debian Jessie, simply installed through apt-get without any issue, with the latest `QT Patched` version installed.
2. **Virtual Machine** with Debian Jessie, simply installed through apt-get without any issue, with the latest version installed (not QT-patched)
3. **Raspberry** with minibian (Jessie), simply installed through apt-get without any issue, some **0.9.4v** installed.

Only the first one allows for the use of `xvfb` and passing further arguments, both 2nd and 3rd have extremely limited options and the rendering is not quite perfect.

The questions are:

- what defines which version will be installed when using apt-get?
- why isn't the installation on the VM trying to fetch the qt-patched version (since both laptop and vm are virtually identical) ?

Comment: We're going to need more information. Obviously, the laptop and VM are not identical but we can't know how. For starters, please [edit] your question and add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and of any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` from each of the machines.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and show the output of `apt-cache policy wkhtmltopdf` on all three systems?

Comment: Sure, as soon as I have a chance to get my hands on all three machines I will update the question.  
In the meantime, is there any general rule I'm not aware of? Or are these specs too much software-related to be considered without further details?